# How to find first pi beginning with 3.14159

Tags: c++, string, pi

For determining how many terms are required for the first time getting pi that begins with 3.14159 I wrote the following program that calculates terms as `(pi = 4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + ...)`.

My problem is that I reached 146063 terms as the result but when I checked, there are many pis that begin similarly before that.

```
//piEstimation.cpp
//estima mathematical pi and detrmin when 
//to get a value beganing with 3.14159

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //initialize vars
    double denominator{1.0};
    double pi{0};
    string piString;
    double desiredPi;    
    int terms;
    int firstDesiredTerm;

    //format output floating point numbers to show 10 digits after 
    // decimal poin
    cout << setprecision (10) <<fixed;

    for (terms = 1;  ; terms++){
        if(0 == terms % 2){ //if term is even
            pi -= 4/denominator;
        }
        else{ //if term is odd
            pi += 4/denominator;
        }

        // draw table
        cout << terms << "\t" << pi << endl;

        //determin first time the pi begains with 3.14159
        piString = to_string(pi).substr(0,7);
        if(piString == "3.14159"){
             firstDesiredTerm = terms;
             desiredPi = pi;
             break;
        }
        denominator += 2;
    }//end for

    cout << "The first time that pi value begans with 3.14159 "
        << "the number of terms are " << firstDesiredTerm << " and pi value is  "<< desiredPi <<endl;
}//end main
```

Comment: A number `x` begins with 3.14159 if `x >= 3.14159 && x < 3.1416`. There is no need to use strings and compare characters. `to_string` has to use some kind of round operation. Do you know how the number is rounded?

Answer (score 2):

A number `x` begins with 3.14159 if `x >= 3.14159 && x < 3.1416`. There is no need to use strings and compare characters. `to_string` has to use some kind of round operation. Without the string the algorithm finds the result after 136121 steps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    //initialize vars
    double denominator{1.0};
    double pi{0};
    double desiredPi;    
    int terms;
    int firstDesiredTerm;

    //format output floating point numbers to show 10 digits after 
    // decimal poin
    std::cout << std::setprecision (20) << std::fixed;

    for (terms = 1;  ; terms++){
        if(0 == terms % 2){ //if term is even
            pi -= 4/denominator;
        }
        else{ //if term is odd
            pi += 4/denominator;
        }

        // draw table
        std::cout << terms << "\t" << pi << std::endl;

        if(pi >= 3.14159 && pi < 3.1416){
             firstDesiredTerm = terms;
             desiredPi = pi;
             break;
        }
        denominator += 2;
    }//end for

    std::cout << "The first time that pi value begans with 3.14159 "
        << "the number of terms are " << firstDesiredTerm 
        << " and pi value is  "<< desiredPi << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
The first time that pi value begans with 3.14159 the number of terms are 136121 and pi value is  3.14159999999478589672
```

Here you can see how `to_string` rounds the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout << std::setprecision (20) << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::to_string(3.14159999999478589672) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3.141600
```

You can read on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

> `std::string to_string( double value );` Converts a floating point value to a string with the same content as what `std::sprintf(buf, "%f", value)` would produce for sufficiently large `buf`.

You can read on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

> `f` `F` Precision specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the decimal point character. The default precision is `6`

That means that `std::to_string` rounds after 6 digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. As a thing more why `pi < 3.1416` is essential in conditional if statement? When I omit this statement the terms increased and result became wrong.

Comment: @Farshid Because `4 >= 3.14159` but it doesn't start with `3.14159`. The smallest number that starts with `3.14159` is `3.14159` and the smallest number larger than `3.14159` that doesn't start with `3.14159` is `3.1416`

Comment: @Farshid I don't understand you. When I remove `pi < 3.1416` in the if condition the output is _"The first time that pi value begans with 3.14159 the number of terms are 1 and pi value is  4.00000000000000000000"_. 4 is obviously larger than `3.14159` but it doesn't start with `3.14159` What is your question?

Comment: Oh dear Tomas. That's true. I became a bit confused in this matter